# Rule of thumb for @property atomicity?

Tags: objective-c

Is there a good rule of thumb for when nonatomic properties should be used in Objective-C (on the desktop or on the iPhone platform), as opposed to the default atomic properties? I understand the difference – atomicity guarantees an entire value at the expense of performance – but most examples I see use nonatomic properties (and aren't unstable), so there are evidently circumstances in which atomicity is required and circumstances under which it is not.

Can anyone provide me with a simple guideline for when I should use atomic properties and when I should favour nonatomic ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should favor `nonatomic` whenever possible. In general, this means properties that will only be set/accessed from a single thread *or* properties whose access is protected by higher-level synchronization of some kind. It's important to note that `atomic` property access does not guarantee thread safety. In other words the algorithms that depend on the values of `atomic` properties must themselves be thread safe for the entire system to be thread safe. With this in mind, it is often possible to make the properties `nonatomic` while maintaining the thread safety of the system.